# Adding spaces in a paragraph if a line is missing

Tags: bash, file, shell, awk

this is probably a very difficult thing to do, or impossible...

I need to look at every paragraph in a file, check if each one contains a certain phrase.
If it doesn't contain the phrase, I need to add a line (eg. line 4 in the paragraph).

Here is an example:

```
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar
Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar
Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry4 = bar
Entry8 = foo
```

Should turn into:

```
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar

Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar


Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar

Entry4 = bar



Entry8 = foo
```

The order of each line will never change (Entry 1 WILL ALWAYS come before Entry 2 assuming they both exist).
There are 14 lines per paragraph, each one needs to be checked (apart from the title which is always there - So only 13 can actually go missing)

Thanks for reading, if you KNOW this is impossible, please say :)

Comment: Why do you want to use `sed`?

Comment: I'd say try a constructive approach instead of trying string processing: read the paragraphs into an associative structure (in a serial manner or in one rush) and then use something like phps array_merge applied to each paragraphs associative representation and a prototyp dummy containing all required entries. Then you serialize the merged arrays again into an output file.

Comment: I don't, I'm making a bash script - Which is using sed for everything, so I assumed this would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks Arkascha, I'm new to Bash so that all went over my head - I'll look into it and see what I can find

Comment: `awk` can do it pretty easily, I'd think.

Comment: Total no of entries in paragraph is always fixed to 4?

Comment: Every paragraph should have 14 lines after the script is run. But almost all the paragraphs are missing 1 or more

Comment: @Adam so you are saying there are just four search criteria (one for each line) which are repeated? What about the order of search criteria?

Comment: The order of them are set in stone, they never change. But there are 14 individual lines which can go missing.
If I can check 1 line, and put a space in the correct place, then I can just modify it for the other 13

Comment: You need to update the question to add that detail and possibly good sample data.

Comment: And while you are editing, maybe edit out the `sed` bias. This is tricky in `sed` but (based on the description so far) sounds easy to do in Awk, Perl, or Python.

Comment: Apologies for not being explicit enough in my question, if this is possible in awk, I'd be very happy to hear ideas. However this is going to be part of a much bigger bash script, so Perl and Python wouldn't be very helpful (Unless it's possible to add them to my existing script, I've got very very limited knowledge of bash as you can tell!)

Comment: I tried adding even more information to the Q. But it was telling me the code was incorrectly formatted, so I can't edit the information anymore.

Comment: What is it you're checking here - that the words "Entry1", etc. literally occur in numerical order at the start of each line or that the word s "foo" and "bar" occur in alternating lines up to a total of 13 occurrences? You tell us that this is about checking for "a certain phrase" but you never say what that phrase is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly isn't very difficult, let alone impossible:

```
/^\[.*\]$/ {
    entry=last=flag=0
    print
    next
}
{
    entry=$1
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",entry)
    if (flag)
    for(i=int(last);i<entry-1;i++)
        print ""
    last=entry
    flag=1
    print
}
```

Save the script to file, say `script.awk` and run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar

Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar


Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar

Entry4 = bar



Entry8 = foo
```

Comment: +1 but do the gsub() and arithmetic on "entry" and then just `print` instead of `print entry,$2` to fix the current formatting issue and so you don't need a `next` and a separate block. I also think you have a bug if the very first entry is missing.

Comment: I won't have a chance to try this until tomorrow, but thanks a lot for going through so much effort!

Comment: I think I've just bumped into a bug, when I have:
Line8 = foo
Line11 = bar
(Can't add ENTERS in comments for some reason)
It doesn't add gaps inbetween them. Does it only work up to 9?

Comment: @Adam correct, It wasn't doing integer comparison.. easy fix, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am just offering another way of solving this. You will be needing two files, one the main file that holds the paragraphs. Second file will hold the keywords in order they are supposed to be encountered.

```
awk '
FNR==NR { # Storing keywords in a hash. 
    a[i++]=$1
    next 
} 
/Paragraph/ { # This can be a regex that denotes start of a new paragraph.
    j=0; 
    print
    next
} 
{ 
    while (NF>1) { 
        if (tmp=match ($0, a[j++])) # If your first line matches to first keyword
            { 
                print $0
                next 
        } 
        else 
            print ""  # If it doesn't match you print blank line and continue back
            continue 
    } 
}1' keywords para
```

#### Test:

```
$ awk '
> FNR==NR { 
>     a[i++]=$1
>     next 
> } 
> /Paragraph/ { 
>     j=0; 
>     print
>     next
> } 
> { 
>     while (NF>1) { 
>         if (tmp=match ($0, a[j++])) 
>             { 
>                 print $0
>                 next 
>         } 
>         else 
>             print "" 
>             continue 
>     } 
> }1' keywords para
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar

Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar


Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar

Entry4 = bar



Entry8 = foo
```

#### Files Used:

```
$ cat keywords 
Entry1
Entry2
Entry3
Entry4
Entry5
Entry6
Entry7
Entry8
Entry9
Entry10

$ cat para 
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar
Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar
Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry4 = bar
Entry8 = foo
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps? Now the OP has to ask another question on how to split his file into the files need for your solution. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sudo_O OP mentioned this in the comments `The order of them (keywords, that is) are set in stone, they never change.` so I am guessing it is not difficult for him to create such a file.

Comment: How does the fact that the data is in sorted order relate? If it isn't difficult for the OP to transform his file into the two required for your answer then I wouldn't be difficult to do the transformation they actually need. This doesn't solve the problem, it complicates it.

Comment: Does your solution work if keyword is not = $1? No right? You based your solution on the assumption that first column is going to be the keyword. I am basing it on the assumption that keywords can be extracted in a file that OP can use to look up missing lines.

Comment: Then OP needs to put that in the question, right? All I read is `paragraphs` and `lines`. So you are assuming it is a config file based on sample data, is it?

Comment: Considering you didn't actually answer the question the OP asked the choice of words the OP used wouldn't have made any difference, is it?

Comment: I answered this question based on the comment OP posted that he knows the order of keywords. If this doesn't help him, yours will right? Lets move on.

Comment: Besides, don't use regex `/Paragraph/`. Paragraph Name need not contain the word `Paragraph`. Use `/\[/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it in `awk`

```
awk -F"Entry| " '/^\[|^$/ {f=1;print;next} {for (i=f;i<=$2;i++) if (i==$2) {print} else {print "";f++};f++}' file
[Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar
Entry3 = foo
Entry4 = bar

Entry6 = foo
Entry7 = bar


Entry10 = foo

[Another Paragraph Name]
Entry1 = foo
Entry2 = bar

Entry4 = bar



Entry8 = foo
```

How does it work:

```
awk -F"Entry| " '               # Sets the Field Separator to "Entry" or " " (Makes it easy to get the number)
    /^\[|^$/ {                  # Run this only if line starts with "[" or is a blank line (^$)
        f=1                     # Set counter to 1
        print                   # Print the line
        next                    # Skip to next record
    }
        {                       # This section is run on all "Entry" lines
        for (i=f;i<=$2;i++)     # Create a loop going from counter f to the number stored in Entry
            if (i==$2) {        # If these two numbers are equal, then:
                print           # print the line
                } 
            else {              # If not equal, then:
                print ""        # print a blank line
                f++             # increase counter
            }
        f++                     # increase counter for every line
    }' file
```